# Make a nav-bar top and nav-bar side fixed to screen

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Here I'm using the twitter bootstrap 3 template:  http://startbootstrap.com/templates/sb-admin-v2/

and `class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top"` on the top
and `class="navbar-default navbar-static-side"`

how I can make it fixed to screen?

I've tried with: `navbar-fixed-top` but that change my conception because I can't then see part of side bar...

Comment: Try adding this class ui-state-persist

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On `navbar-static-side`, add css

```
position: fixed;
top: 65px;
```

On `navbar`, add

```
position:fixed;
width: 100%;
```

That fixes them both to the page.

Comment: also try user3393142's suggestions on the `navbar-static-side`, you can use `position: fixed; bottom:0px`

Answer (score 2):

Not sure I understand what it is you need here, but.. if it is your fixed navbar -at the top of the page- which is hiding the sidebar (static-item), you should consider adding a little bit of padding to the top of the body. If you decide to use fixed positioning for the sidebar, as well as the navbar.. you'll have to use `top` or `bottom` to distance it from the top of the page manually.

Answer (score 1):

Just put `<p style="margin: 35px;"></p>` after `<body>`. And gotcha! you will see fixed navbar without any problem again!